# How exactly does the trap EXIT function and the "sleep n && function" operate in bash with regards to variables?

Tags: bash, function, variables, sleep

Here is a script that reproduces my problem. The function echos and changes the variable. It doesn't matter if I press a key first or let the timer run out first, the variable does not change for both calls, it just prints "Not touched!" twice, which is very strange to me.

```
#!/bin/bash

func(){
    echo "$globalVar"       
    globalVar="touched!"
}

globalVar="Not touched!"

trap func EXIT
(sleep 3 && func) &

read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to exit..."
```

I expect it to echo "Not touched!" the first time and "toched!" the second time.

Edit:
Has to do with the (sleep 3 && func) $ line using a background process. My question then would be how do I make the variable really global?

Comment: There's no way to make a "really global" variable across multiple processes. The closest you can get is to store a value in the file, and read/write that file from the different processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Traps

The `trap` built-in is specified by posix `sh` and bash is bound by that specification. From the [official specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/trap.html):

> The environment in which the shell executes a trap on EXIT shall be identical to the environment immediately after the last command executed before the trap on EXIT was taken.
>
> Each time trap is invoked, the action argument shall be processed in a manner equivalent to:
>
> `eval action`

That should answer the question in your title. However, your script is affect by another other detail that can be a bit confusing:

#### Subshells

Inside a subprocess, you cannot change the variables of the parent process. This might seem obvious if you have a command like ...

```
#! /bin/bash
x=1
bash -c 'x=2'
echo "$x"
```

... but bash starts so called subshells in a lot of places, e.g. in pipes (`subshell1 | subshell2`), substitutions `command "$(subshell)"`, background processes `subshell &` and explicit subshells `(subshell)`.

`(sleep 3 && func) &` runs in a subshell and therefore cannot alter the global variable **of the parent process**.

#### Inter-Process Communication

> My question then would be how do I make the variable really global?

If you want to have a shared variable between two processes, that's simply not possible with built-ins. You need some way to do inter-process communication. The simplest solution for that in shells is to read and write files/fifos. The details depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve.